# Extending arrows with overset text

Tags: symbols, arrows, width

I'd like to extend an arrow to allow better readability of characters which are overset using `\overset{}{}` .

Right now I have

```
 \overset{k_1}{\rightleftharpoons}
```

which produces:

[image]

and this leaves the subscript awfully close the to harpoon arrow. Thus, is there anyway to just extend the character length?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are several packages supporting extensible arrows:

- [amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) (`\xleftarrow` etc., new commands could be similarly created)
- [extarrows](http://ctan.org/pkg/extarrows)
- [extpfeil](http://ctan.org/pkg/extpfeil)
- [mathtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)

An example suitable for your formula, also demonstrating the optional argument for text under the arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[ \xrightleftharpoons[k_2]{\,k_1\,} \]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you, that solves the problem exactly. I've never used mathtools before.

Comment: Is it possible to use this command in the 'report' environment?

Comment: @Guilherme Yes, it is, no change needed.

Comment: But I am using ''\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{report}'' and do not works.

Comment: @Guilherme It works, check this link: [Run with TeXlive.net](https://texlive.net/run?%5Cdocumentclass%5B10pt,%20a4paper%5D%7Breport%7D%0D%0A%5Cusepackage%7Bmathtools%7D%0D%0A%5Cbegin%7Bdocument%7D%0D%0A%5C%5B%20%5Cxrightleftharpoons%5Bk_2%5D%7B%5C,k_1%5C,%7D%20%5C%5D%0D%0A%5Cend%7Bdocument%7D)

Comment: Is it possible to move $$k_2$$ up to be closer to the arrow? `raisebox` seems not to work.