# How to get text above and below double harpoon (reversible reaction) symbols in an equation

Tags: symbols, characters

I'm working on the Chemwiki Dynamic Textbook Project at UC Davis, California and I've run into a problem.
I need to formulate a symbol containing double harpoons (as in a reversible reaction, e.g. `\rightleftharpoons`); however, I need to have text both above and below the harpoons.
I have an image I can email, but I can't post with an image because I'm new to this.

I can find code for `\overleftrightarrow` and `\underleftrightarrow`, but that's not quite what I need. I need both, on the same expression.
If anyone has a minute to help me, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: If you don't mind using TikZ, a quite similar (if not the same) problem was solved in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10166/how-do-i-position-pairs-of-arrows-in-tikz-to-make-harpoons).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extending arrows with overset text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5225/extending-arrows-with-overset-text)

Answer (score 31):

You could use the features provided by the [mhchem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) package. A little example, taken from the package documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\ce{
Zn^2+
<=>[\ce{+ 2OH-}][\ce{+ 2H+}]
$\underset{\text{amphoteres Hydroxid}}{\ce{Zn(OH)2 v}}$
<=>[\ce{+2OH-}][\ce{+ 2H+}]
$\underset{\text{Hydroxozikat}}{\ce{[Zn(OH)4]^2-}}$
}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: I think there is a typo in the last line: It should be "\ce{[Zn(OH)4]^2-}", right?

Answer (score 17):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

$\mathrm{A} \xrightleftharpoons[k_2]{k_1} \mathrm{B}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, can you please extend your answer to cover the duplicate suggested under the question?

Comment: done. I replaced \rightleftharpoons with \xrightleftharpoons.

Comment: `\rm` was deprecated around twenty years ago. It's not part of the LaTeX commands.

Comment: Yes, I know. It still works, though, and it's shorter than \mathrm but point taken. I edited my response.

Answer (score 11):

A simple one-line solution which worked for me was:

```
X \underset{k_2}{\stackrel{k_1}{\rightleftharpoons}} Y
```

[image]

But the harpoon arrows don't extend when the text above and below is longer.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to [mhchem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) would be the [chemmacros](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) bundle (including `chemformula`) by our user [@cgnieder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049/cgnieder).

The syntax is simple and (pretty) intuitive, in many ways similar to the syntax of `mhchem`.

Here is a minimal example and the output.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemformula}%loaded by chemmacros
\begin{document}
\ch{Zn^2+ 
<>[ + 2 OH- ][ + 2 H+ ]%Reaction in both directions
!(amphoteres~Hydroxid)( Zn(OH)2 v )
<=>[ + 2 OH- ][ + 2 H+ ]%Equilibrium arrow
!(Hydroxozikat)( [Zn(OH)4]^2- )
}
\end{document}![chemmacros output][1]
```

There is much more handy stuff in the bundle. Check out the documentation for more or the [blog of the author](http://www.mychemistry.eu/category/packages/chemmacros/).