# How do I display things above and below an arrow?

Tags: subscripts, superscripts, latex-misc

Really tried to code this one on my own, but I have no luck in doing so so far! 
[image]

I can do everything in this problem, except the alpha and beta above and beneath the arrows. I believe that alpha is a superscript and beta is a subscript to the arrows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might be interested to see some of the answers to the related issued common in typesetting chemistry https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14957/how-to-get-text-above-and-below-double-harpoon-reversible-reaction-symbols-in

Comment: For future questions, it would be nice to give us what you can do so far, so that we have something to go from.  And try to have a title that is more search friendly, since yours could apply to every question on this site.

Comment: @Teepeemm I elaborated on what I can do in the question. Can you be more specific as to what is a title that is more search friendly? It seems that it was very friendly, as I have already received an excellent answer to my query. :)

Comment: Sorry about that.  By "what you can do so far", I meant the minimal working code example that has `\[S_0 \leftrightarrow S_1\]` (clearly I don't know how to do that arrow offhand).  You got an answer because you asked the question recently, so it's on the front page of the site.  But once it's off the front page, people won't be able to find it.  Maybe "How do I display things above and below an arrow?"

Comment: @Teepeeman Changed the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another simple approach is to use the `\overset` and `\underset` commands with the `\leftrightarrows` symbol like so:

```
\overset{\alpha}{\underset{\beta}{\leftrightarrows}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A simple-minded approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$S_0\mathrel{\raisebox{2pt}{$\xrightarrow{\alpha}$}
\llap{\raisebox{-2pt}{$\xleftarrow[\beta]{}$}}} S_1$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or a more extensive solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
S_0\arrow[r,shift left=2pt,"\alpha"] & \arrow[l,shift left=2pt,"\beta"] S_1
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thank-you!