# Extended \Mapsto with text above

Tags: math-mode, arrows

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ stmaryrd }

\begin{document}
    $\xmapsto{sdfkjhsdf}$ % This is similar to what I want

    $\Mapsto$ % however I need this kind of arrow

    %$\xMapsto{sdfkjhsdf}$ % does not exist - results in error
\end{document}
```

Output of the first two:

[image: xMapsto]

I want an extensible `mapsto` with writing on top like the first, but with an arrow like the second. Is there a way to do this from the existing packages?

Comment: Is `\Longmapsto` enough for you?

Comment: Should be `\longmapsto`, it exists.

Comment: Very similar: [math mode - \xRightarrow (text) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85113/xrightarrow-text), [symbols - Extending arrows with overset text - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5225/extending-arrows-with-overset-text/5229#5229)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `mathtools` package provides nearly everything you need to construct this, and `stmaryrd` has the extra pieces of symbols.  Putting these together gives

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xMapsto}[2][]{\ext@arrow 0599{\Mapstofill@}{#1}{#2}}
\def\Mapstofill@{\arrowfill@{\Mapstochar\Relbar}\Relbar\Rightarrow}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
   \mapsto \qquad \xmapsto[A]{sdfkjhsdf} \\
 \Mapsto \qquad \xMapsto[A]{sdfkjhsdf}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

The parameters `0599` are for the placement of the labels and how much the arrow extends over them.  I have use the same numbers as `mathtools` does for `\xmapsto`.  `\Mapstochar` is the short bar at the beginning, from the `stmaryrd` package, `\Relbar` is the double line which fits with final `\Rightarrow`.  The internal macros names include the `@` character, so have to be included in a `\makeatletter / \makeatother` pair.

It might have been nice to use the [`extpfeil` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/extpfeil) for this, but unfortunately it loads `stmaryrd` with clashing options.

Comment: I was about to post the same answer. `;-)`

Comment: why do i get an error saying that `mathtools` does not exists? MicTex 2.9 X64, Win7 X64.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu That sounds like a completely separate question.  May be http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187725/15925 helps.

Comment: when i type \xmapsto{A} then there is a normal rightarrow with a 7 at the start..

Comment: @LillienSabrinaGluch I can not reproduce that; it works fine for me.  Perhaps you could ask a separate question posting the code you try.

Answer (score 3):

The `fp` package is used to calculate the appropriate width of the arrow.  The kerns will be important if you change fonts.  It's set up to provide an arrow length of a certain minimum width, regardless of the over/underset.  THen, as the over/underset grows, the arrow width will grow with it.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{fp}
\def\clipeq{\kern -.65pt\mathrm{=}\kern -1pt}
\def\Lla{\rule[-.1ex]{.3pt}{1.3ex}}
\def\Lra{\kern -3.5pt\Longrightarrow}
\newcount\argwidth
\newcount\clipeqwidth
\savestack\tempstack{\stackon{$\clipeq$}{}}%
\clipeqwidth=\wd\tempstackcontent\relax
\newcommand\xMapsto[2]{%
  \savestack\tempstack{\stackon{$\scriptstyle#1$}{$\scriptstyle#2$}}%
  \argwidth=\wd\tempstackcontent\relax%
  \FPdiv\scalefactor{\the\argwidth}{\the\clipeqwidth}%
  \FPsub\scalefactor{\scalefactor}{1.5}% <---CAN PLAY WITH THIS VALUE
  \FPmax\scalefactor{\scalefactor}{.05}%
  \mathrel{%
  \stackunder[2pt]{\stackon[3pt]{$\Lla\hstretch{\scalefactor}{\clipeq}\Lra$}%
     {$\scriptstyle#1~$}}{$\scriptstyle#2~$}%
  }%
}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document} 
$X \xMapsto{ABC}{defghi} Y$

$\xMapsto{}{}$

$\xMapsto{a}{}$

$\xMapsto{ab}{}$

$\xMapsto{abc}{}$

$\xMapsto{abcd}{}$

$\xMapsto{abcde}{}$
\end{document}
```

[image]