# How to install mathtools package?

Tags: miktex, installing

I'm new to Latex so forgive me if the questions are dumb...

I was trying to right left-top corner superscript, someone recommended mathtools package on this forum: [Left and right subscript / superscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11542/left-and-right-subscript).

So I downloaded [mathtools.zip from CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools), unzip it, there's an "mathtools.dtx".
In the package there are documents but none talked about how to install, I fancy the installation is just too primary to real Latex users.

OK, then, there's still another thread here explained the steps: [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows) . So here I follow

1. I ran "tex XXX.dtx" (there's no *.ins files) on all the .dtx files under the extracted folder, that includes: breqn.dtx, flexisym.dtx, mathstyle.dtx, empheq.dtx, mathtools.
2. Then I created a folder "C:\athos\localtexmf\mathtools" and put all the new files in.
3. Then I go to "Windows -> Start -> Programs -> MikTex 2.9 -> Maintenance (Admin) -> Settings (Admin) "; in "Roots" tab I added path "C:\athos\localtexmf"; in "General" tab I clicked "Refresh FNDB" and then clicked "OK" to close it.
4. I restarted my WinEdt, added 
   "\usepackage{mathtools}" under "\documentclass..."; and added "test  $\prescript{14}{2}{\mathbf{C}}$
   " in the main body.

After that when I try to "MikTex", the error still comes up:
"The required file tex\latex\mh\mathtools\sty is missing. It is a part of the following pakage: mh . The package will be installed from ..."

Seems the folder "C:\athos\localtexmf\mathtools" is not captured by MikTex?

Then in the error message dialog, I choose "Change", choose "Package shall be installed from a directory", click "Next", choose ""C:\athos\localtexmf\" or "C:\athos\localtexmf\mathtools", in either try it says "Not a local package repository".

What shall I do?

I'm on Microsoft Windows XP Prefessional SP3, WinEdt 8 (Build: 20140613  (v. 8.2) - 32-bit), and MikTex 2.9.

Comment: You should install `mh` from MiKTeX's package manager, you'll have no problem. Why do you want to install manually a package that's in the distribution?

Comment: @Bernard let's say rookies shoot their foot :p

Comment: Hi. I try to install the mathtools from mh bundles in the package manager, but it shows 'Error response from server: 404' . May I know how to solve this problem?

Comment: @idonknow my problem was that in my company there was a proxy, it works perfect for browsers but seems the TeX update does not recognize it. Not knowing how to config TeX proxy, I did the update at home , where my WiFi has no proxy

Comment: **In August 2014**, the `mh` bundle of packages was broken up into two parts. The advice sought (and given) in this posting about installing the `mh` bundle is no longer applicable for versions of TeXLive and MikTeX more recent than August 2014.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have installed MikTeX 2.9 (on Windows) is very easy. You can go to

`Home->Programs->MiKTeX 2.9->Maintenance (Admin)->Package Manager (Admin)`

Alternative path to admin exe file
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin

or without `(Admin)` if you want to install the new packages in a local directory. There you can choose any package and to install it by clicking in `+` button. In case of the `mathtools` package you can find it in the `mh` bundle (it appears in the list of installable packages) and provides a se­ries of pack­ages de­signed to en­hance the ap­pear­ance of doc­u­ments con­tain­ing a lot of math­e­mat­ics (`mathtools` included).

### Edit

From August 19'th 2014 the `mh` bundle has disappeared in `MiKTeX`, now it's possible to find the `mathtools` package separately.

Comment: It started to download and failed : "connect failed in tcp_connect()" -- I'm behind a firewall, may I check how to set the proxy?

Comment: @athos Try again, and make sure you have a good internet connection or choose another download server (`mirror`).

Comment: do you mean that i don't need to set up the proxy server ip etc? mmm, if so i guess the reason is the proxy prohibited some files (.exe or too big file), let me try it at home.

Comment: So... no longer possible to use `mathtools` at all? Your Oct 1, 2014 edit is not very clear to a tex noob.

Comment: I can use tool `mathtool` with MiKTeX. In my package manager it is listed with the packaging date 2014-08-19 and I can run it! So edit 2 seems to be obsolet ...

Comment: Just install TeXLive. It's a complete tex distribution and you won't need to about packages anymore. The only disadvantage is its size. Updating is also very simple, thanks to the tlmgr.

Answer (score 30):

@romkyns

I had the same problem with `mathtools` and `MiKTeX` today, the same initial error about the missing .sty file. Going to:

`MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin`

I ran `mpm_mfc_admin`, went to the Repository tab at the top and clicked synchronise. `mathtools` is now in my package list and I can confirm it works; no more missing .sty file.

[image: Mathtools in MiKTeX Package Manager (Admin) as of 14/11/14]