# problems installing mathtools

Tags: packages, miktex, installing, mathtools

There have been a few questions regarding installing this package in the past, but they now seem to be out of date. I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 and TexMaker. When I try `\usepackage{mathtools}` in TexMaker it will try to install the package for me but will fail. I took the advice given in this thread:
[How to install mathtools package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187725/how-to-install-mathtools-package)

As suggested I tried installing the `mh` package using the MiKTeX Package Manager, unfortunately I get the "unknown archive size" error, which I have read means that the package no longer exists. Another thread (lost the link) said you can use the MiKTeX Package Manager to directly install `mathtools`, however I do not see `mathtools` listed anywhere in the MiKTeX Package Manager...

So I ask, is the package under a different name? Are there any other ways to install this package?

Comment: early in august (2014), the `mh` bundle was broken in two: `mathtools` and `breqn` will be maintained separately from now on.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see mathtools on the package manager list anywhere (or breqn for that matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is a bug in the MikTeX 5105 basic installer. Using it ("basic-miktex-2.9.5105"), i encountered the issue stated here; the "mathtools" and "breqn" packages do not appear and the "mh" package installation fails with the error mentioned earlier.

To circumvent this problem until a fix is released, download the net installer instead  ("setup-2.9.4503"); it's version 4503 which seems to work just fine.

Comment: I can't believe it, since 2011 September the latest version is still 2.9.5105?

Comment: Given the popularity of [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204724/31839), it seems like maybe this one should be removed.

Answer (score 38):

Had the same issue. For me it worked after I synchronized manually with the repository using the **MikTeX Package Manager (Admin)** tool and under the Repository menu using the **synchronize**.

Then the issue is resolved and the `mathtools` package appears under the package list.

Comment: I did not need to use the admin version.

Answer (score 5):

In `cmd` type `mpm --verify=mathtools` that will tell if `mathtools` is installed, not installed or unknown.

If `mathtools` is not installed: in `cmd` type `mpm --install=mathtools` to install `mathtools`.

If `mathtools` is unknown: in `cmd` type `mpm --find-updates` or `mpm --update-db` and then install.

Alternative: in `cmd` type `mpm` to start MiKTeX Package Manager then **Repository**->**Synchronize**

[image: Find mathtools]

Then search for `mathtools` -> select row `mathtools` -> right click -> install.

Answer (score 4):

The `mh` package has recently been split into `mathtools` and `breqn`, with different maintainers, and they certainly appear in MiKTeX Package Manager:

[image]

Which version of mpm do you have?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by mpm. I have miktex 2.9, on windows 7. I see the mh bundle like you showed, but when I try and install it I get the "unknown archive file size error".

Comment: `Mpm`is the acronym for `MiKTeX` package manager. It mentions the `mh `package, but it's an error: it was removed from the archive, as you can see on looking at CTAN (for instance at http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/). You now must install separately `mathtools` and `breqn`.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up downloading and manually installing the mathtools package, this was easier I think than switching to an earlier version of miktex. I think emher is right and that this is a bug in miktex 5105 where those two packages just don't appear in the list. For anyone else with the same problem you can download the package [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools).

To install the package I typed "latex mhsetup.dtx" followed by "latex mathtools.dtx" in the windows command line (after cd'ing to the directory I downloaded the package first of course).