# Cannot find amsmath amstools package even though the doc used to compile

Tags: math-mode, packages, package-options

[image]

This is from a document that used to compile. I want to use it as a template as it was a really good template.

However when I press compile it says that it cannot find the amsmath or amstools packages. I have included a screenshot.

Furthermore, I cannot see how these packages can be installed.

Comment: What distribution do you use? When did you update your distribution?

Comment: Im not sure what a distribution is? @Werner

Comment: Sorry I meant the mathtools package not amstools. see screenshot. @Bernard

Comment: @1234: See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Comment: There recently has been a problem with mathtools in MiKTeX distribution: as the `mh` bundle was split into `mathtools` and `breqn`, it was removed (including mathtools) without being replaced. If it's the case, the solution consists in synchronizing the file name database in MiKTeX Package Manager, then installing mathtools (and possibly breqn if you're interested in).

Comment: I am not sure how you would synchronize the file name database in MikTeX Package Manager. Will this sort out the problem with amsmath? @Bernard

Comment: No; it can only solve an hypothetic problem with mathtools for `MiKTeX` users. It would be better to have a minimal (non) working example. Btw, if you load mathtools, you don't have to load amsmath.

Comment: Sorry whats mi?

Comment: *I* am sorry for this mistyping. See the edit.

Comment: So what are you suggesting as the solution to the mathtools problem?

Comment: Check if mathtools is installed with MiKTeX Package Manager, after you've synchronised. If (as I suppose) it isn't, install it. If it is, well… it's a more complex problem.

Comment: see [problems installing mathtools](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199883/579) (the same problem that @Bernard has already commented).