# Vertically equalities in align should be even

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I want to know how to make a proper align where the equalites should be even vertically.

```
\begin{align*}
\Gamma(\lambda_{1})\Gamma(\lambda_{2})&=\int_{(0,\infty)^{2}}\phi(u,v)\, \mathrm{d}m_{2}(u,v)\\
&\overset{12.15}=\int_{(0,\infty)\times (0,1)}x^{(\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2})-1}e^{-x}y^{\lambda_{1}-1}(1-y)^{\lambda_{2}-1}\mathrm{d}m_{2}(x,y)\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}x^{(\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2})-1}e^{-x}y^{\lambda_{1}-1}(1-y)^{\lambda_{2}-1}\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}`
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would merely go with a `\mathclap` of the over-set item:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \Gamma(\lambda_{1})\Gamma(\lambda_{2})&=\int_{(0,\infty)^{2}}\phi(u,v)\, \mathrm{d}m_{2}(u,v)\\
  &\overset{\mathclap{12.15}}{=} \int_{(0,\infty)\times (0,1)}x^{(\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2})-1}e^{-x}y^{\lambda_{1}-1}(1-y)^{\lambda_{2}-1}\mathrm{d}m_{2}(x,y)\\
  &=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}x^{(\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2})-1}e^{-x}y^{\lambda_{1}-1}(1-y)^{\lambda_{2}-1}\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

`\mathclap` (provided by [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools), which loads [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) by default) eliminates the horizontal width of its argument.

Comment: #Werner. Thanks. I'm unable to download the mathtools package in MiKTeX (v. 2.9.4248) since it mysteriously doesn't exist (anymore). I have tried looking similar in other pages and I still didn't get what I needed. Is there another way to command in LaTeX?

Comment: @AjmalW: Instead of `\mathclap{12.15}`, you can use `\makebox[0pt]{$\scriptstyle 12.15$}`.

Comment: @AjmalW: Also see [Problems installing `mathtools`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199883/5764).