# Looking for template for landscape columnwise cheat-sheet type of document

Tags: templates, paper-size

I want to make a cheat-sheet with geometry formulas which I can use a background on a 1600x1280 screen. I am looking for a template or just the lines of code i have to use to setup my latex document. I want to use a small font such that I can use six columns. - This is probably a no brainer question but would probably take me hours to figure out and test.

Additionally is it possible to linearly add my texts and formulas such that latex decides how to distribute the text over the columns? Or is that too much 'word processing thinking' instead of type-setting?

EDIT:
Christian Hupfer setup does the job. But for `1600x1280` ( or your screen-size ) I assume https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Page_size_and_margins this is needed as well.

Comment: How about a cheat-sheet on `multicols` package, for example? ;-)

Comment: No problem if I need to import a package.

Comment: Isn't multicols always required if you work with multiple columns?

Comment: No, you could use `twocolumn` option if the class supports this -- you will have -- you guess it already -- have only two columns, of course ;-)

Comment: Ok. I need -at least- four, preferably six.

Comment: `paracols` could be another optional package

Comment: Have you used paracols in four/six column layout, do you have a template for me, or config info?

Comment: You might also use a `tabular` to do that.

Comment: @Johannes_B: `tabular` does not reflow from one column to the next one (if that's an issue at all)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Correcct, but is that really needed for a cheat-sheet? This is something that requires manual interference.

Comment: Reflow would be nice, that's all.

Comment: @Johannes_B: not for me ... ah, ndroock1 has already said: Yes!

Comment: See edit in question, with that I can start. Will accept answer after advised waiting time.

Comment: You are aware that `1600x1260` is no paper size? I am not sure how this can be achieved with `geometry` at all. It will be scaled somehow, of course ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\usepackage[margin=1cm,paperheight=25.6cm,paperwidth=32cm]{geometry}`? (without `landscape` as a class argument) Edit: The numbers are not entirely random, 32 = 1600/100*2, and 25.6 = 1280/100*2. So you get the correct aspect ratio at least.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.Thanks, the `landscape` option was a mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible starter, but nothing more: Six columns with some sample formula and `\columnbreak` commands to -- well break the column.

If this is not required, the text flows from one column to the next one!

Any decorations are subject to the O.P!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{6}
\begin{itemize}
\item Pythagorean Theorem:

  \[ c^2 = a^2 + b^2 \]

\columnbreak

\item Trigonometry

\begin{itemize}[label={$\triangleright$}]
\item  $\sin \alpha = \dfrac{b}{c} $
\item  $\cos \alpha = \dfrac{b}{c} $
\end{itemize}

\columnbreak

\item Area of circle:

  \[ A = \pi r^2 \]

\columnbreak

\item Volume of Sphere

\[ V = \dfrac{4}{3} \pi r^3 \]

\columnbreak

\item Pythagorean Theorem:

  \[ c^2 = a^2 + b^2 \]

\columnbreak

\item Pythagorean Theorem:

  \[ c^2 = a^2 + b^2 \]


\end{itemize}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The rest is my task, of course. Will try this -now-.

Comment: It says File `mathtools.sty' not found. \usepackage

Comment: Texstudio and Miktex are configured such that packages not found are automatically downloaded.

Comment: @ndroock1: Yes, but that has nothing to do with my solution. Use `amsmath` then instead of `mathtools` -- I always install the full distribution

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199883/problems-installing-mathtools

Comment: It worked with amsmath, this is definitely a start. Thank you very much for your time.