# Equation numbering in square brackets

Tags: equations, numbering

Does anyone knows how can I use square brackets instead of parenthesis when numbering my equations?

I used this command:

```
\begin{equation}
y = 2x
\end{equation}
```

[image]

The number appears on the right hand side like (1) I want to make it [1].

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I want to make it [1]. In square bracket not in parenthesis

Comment: How do you want to refer to those equations? With `[1]` too?

Comment: See `mathtools`, one of its features is to control the formatting of the equation number.

Answer (score 15):

This is much simpler if you load `mathtools`, an add-on package for amsmath:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtagform{brackets}{[}{]}
\usetagform{brackets}

\begin{document}

  \begin{equation}\label{eq:test}
    y = 2x
  \end{equation}

  See eq~\eqref{eq:test}.
\end{document}
```

Result: 
[image]

Comment: For some reason I can't download the mathtools. I check to package manager (Admin) but it's not there

Comment: mathtools is part of texlive and i think of miktex too

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187728/59716

Answer (score 4):

If package `amsmath` is loaded, then it uses `\tagform@` for the formatting of the equation number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{[\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr]}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:y=2x}
  y = 2x
\end{equation}
Equation \eqref{eq:y=2x}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Standard LaTeX uses `\@eqnum` for this purpose:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@eqnnum}{{\normalfont \normalcolor [\theequation]}}
\makeatother
```