# How to make cleveref cross-references match a modified equation label style?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, cleveref

I know that `\eqref` exactly matches the style of the reference to the style of the equation label. However, I prefer to use `\cref` from the `cleveref` package because (1) it allows me to place the word Equation before the number and because (2) it allows me type `\cref{eq1,eq2}` quite comfortably. Further, following [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240360/equation-numbering-in-square-brackets), I'm redefining the style of the equation number delimiters. Unluckily, such a change is not captured by the `cleveref` package.

Here goes a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,]{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{[\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr]}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \cref{eq1} is fancy
    \begin{equation}\label{eq1}
        a = b
    \end{equation}  
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Then, my question is: **how can I get the round parentheses to become square brackets?**

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: See the `mathtools` package for its `\newtagform` macro as well in order to simplify such styles of equation tags

Comment: Do you mean that `mathtools` provides easier ways to do what I'm doing?

Comment: Regarding the style of tags `mathtools` is helping you definitely, but I think the `\cref` issue still persists, however. `mathtools` loads `amsmath` (and extends it) so you will be able to use everything you already applied from `amsmath`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my point of view the easiest (though not most elegant, perhaps) way is to change `\creflabelformat` for the `equation` counter as well, applying the `\tagform@` macro explicitly for this.

```
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2\tagform@{#1}#3}
```

The `#2` and `#3` are reserved for `hyperref` targets.

Here's the full code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,]{cleveref}


\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{[\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr]}}

\creflabelformat{equation}{#2\tagform@{#1}#3}

\makeatother





\begin{document}
    \cref{eq1} is fancy
    \begin{equation}\label{eq1}
        a = b
    \end{equation}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The following solution uses the `\newtagform` and `\usetagform` macros of the `mathtools` package and the `\creflabelformat` macro of the `cleveref` package to achieve your formatting objective.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\newtagform" macro
\newtagform{brackets}{[}{]}
\usetagform{brackets} % employ square brackets as delimiters around eq. numbers

\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2{\upshape[#1]}#3}

\begin{document}
\cref{eq1} is fancy.
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
        a = b
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wonder whether the second occurrence of `#2` should instead be `#3` (viz., in `\creflabelformat{equation}{#2{\upshape[#1]}#2}`)?

From the [`cleveref` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf), §8.1.2: The `<format>` argument “should contain the three arguments `#1`, `#2` and `#3`, the first being the formatted version of the label counter, the others determining the beginning and end of the portion that becomes a hyperlink when the hyperref package is loaded…. `#2` and `#3` must appear in that order."

Comment: @JimRatliff - Many thanks for contacting me and for pointing out the error. I've fixed the code. Best, Mico