# Changing position and controlling style of equation label (AMS, Hebrew+English, XeLatex)

Tags: xetex, equations, amsmath, polyglossia, hebrew

I am using TeXworks (Windows 10, MiKTeX), compiling (XeLatex) a document that contains several languages, but attached is a simplified MWE which contains only Hebrew and English.
Inside the Hebrew environment, I would like to be able to control most of the properties of the label, primarily its position and style: altering the position from the typical right to the left, and controlling style through independent control of size, a different font, boldface, color, etc.
I followed the comments and solutions provided in the forum, but the position of the label does not change. 
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin=2cm,hmargin=2cm,showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{bidi}

\makeatletter\chardef\l@hebrew=255 \makeatother %removes the Hebrew hyphenation problem/warning

\setmainlanguage{english}

\setotherlanguages{hebrew} 

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Mapping=tex-text,Script=Hebrew,Scale=1,FakeBold=0]{Taamey Frank CLM}


\title{Hebrew and English Math AND Text in \LaTeX}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
This is a mainly English document which contains other languages.

\section{Hebrew and English}
Here's some Hebrew and English text:

\begin{hebrew}
שיוויון פשוט:\newline

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\input{leqno.clo}
\makeatother
\begin{equation}
\label{1}
a=b
\end{equation}
\endgroup

\end{hebrew}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you want the equation number *always* on the left or only *sometimes* on the left?

Comment: You can change the format of the equation number by redefining `\tagform@`. See `amsmath-xetex-bidi.def` for its definition when `bidi` is loaded. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240365/87678 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61768/87678

Comment: To put the equation temporarily on the left you can use `\let\veqno\leqno` after your `\begingroup`

Answer (score 1):

If you always want numbers on the left, load `bidi` with the `leqno` option. Otherwise you can change it whenever you want by setting `\veqno` be equal to `\leqno`.

You can change the equation number style by redefining `\theequation`. (See also  the `amsmath` `\numberwithin` macro.)

You can change the format of the tag by redefining `\tagform@`. Note that `bidi` also redefines this in `amsmath-xetex-bidi.def`.

## Silly MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{hebrew} 
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{SBL BibLit}
\begin{document}
\section{Hebrew and English}
Here's some Hebrew and English text:

\begin{hebrew}
שיוויון פשוט:

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\emph{\thesection}\textcolor{green}{.}\textbf{\arabic{equation}}}
\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\Large\if@nonlatin\beginR\fi\textcolor{blue}{+}\kern\z@\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr\textcolor{red}{+}\if@nonlatin\endR\fi}}
\makeatother
\let\veqno\leqno
\begin{equation}
\label{1}
a=b
\end{equation}
\endgroup

\end{hebrew}

See equation \ref{1}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! A very simple and clear solution that actually works! Much obliged, Gideon

Comment: @Gideon you should accept answers that you think fit best to your questions. This way, other users will know that this is a suitable answer to your question. :)