# Where can I get datetime2.sty or what is CTAN?

Tags: ctan, datetime2

I am trying to build a huge latex project on my system - I downloaded everything, and did not touch anything. XeLaTeX tells me that datetime2.sty is missing, and I guess I just have to download it, and put it in the project folder?

But I can not find it online: Either I end up with pdf files that tell me something about other languages, or I get the link to CTAN, and it has only files with other endings, so I don't really understand why I get linked there?

(This happens quite often and this CTAN thing NEVER had a useful file for me, so I figure I just don't know how to use it, and it certainly doesn't seem intuitive.)

Comment: Re "what is CTAN", see my short paragraph here: https://latex.zeef.com/sean.allred#block_58836_what-s-ctan-

Comment: What distribution do you have? Both TeXLive and MiKTeX include the package, so you can use their package managers to install it.

Comment: So it doesn't actually have the packages, only the documentation?

Comment: The package is actually embedded in the documentation. The 'ins' file is an 'install' file; running `latex` on it will extract the necessary files from the `dtx` (Documented (La)TeX). But again, I would use your package manager; there are GUI managers in both TeXLive and MiKTeX. It would help greatly if you let us know which distribution you have :)

Comment: About the distribution ... how can I find it out? I guess I installed something along with Texmaker a long time ago, but I do not really know what. Also where can I find it? I thought it was something for the "background" like fonts?

Comment: A distribution is like an organization that collects TeX-related files (like datetime2), tools (like TeXmaker), and TeX engines/formats (like `pdflatex`). You could just search your computer for 'MiKTeX' or 'TeXLive' (or 'MacTeX', etc.)

Comment: Ohhh ... so thats how it works ... Ok, I definitely do not know enough about this stuff ... How can i run latex? On a file? Sorry, I am completely confused ... I always only used it to produce some documents :/

Comment: Please, please, *please* use your package manager :( When you downloaded LaTeX, where did you download it from?

Comment: `datetime2` is pretty new, and has only recently superseded `datetime`. Is the project you are typesetting one that has been updated very recently?

Comment: Oh boy ... I have no idea, and a simple search returns no results for neither TexLive nor MikTex ... In the part where it shows the installed software on windows I also dont see neither. And in Texmaker on all options and paths I dont seem to also find a hint on what I installed.

Comment: Yes, the project is very recent, in fact it is this one: [https://github.com/rjl20/hpmor/ ]

Comment: OK, what does `pdftex --version` at the command line/terminal print?

Comment: `MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.4902 (1.40.14) (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
Copyright (C) 1982 D. E. Knuth, (C) 1996-2012 Han The Thanh
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.`

Comment: There you are; you're using MiKTeX. MiKTeX's package manager will be in the Start Menu; find it, run the 'admin' version, search for `datetime2` in the program, and install it.

Comment: OK, you have an up-to-date MiKTeX. What you need to do is synchronize the package database then run the update wizard. Do that _both_ in 'normal' and 'admin' modes, if you have 'admin' mode. That should find `datetime2` without you needing to do a manual install.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187728/17423

Comment: Oh wow, that was it! Thank you for your solutions and especially your patience!

Comment: I've tried to `latex datetime2.ins' and gotten !Undefined control sequence: \preamble. I'm running Tex Live on Ubuntu. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, in case another dummy like me has the same problem, here are some most important comments that helped me:

"The package is actually embedded in the documentation. The 'ins' file is an 'install' file; running latex on it will extract the necessary files from the dtx (Documented (La)TeX). But again, I would use your package manager; there are GUI managers in both TeXLive and MiKTeX. It would help greatly if you let us know which distribution you have :)" by Sean Alfred

"OK, what does pdftex --version at the command line/terminal print?" by Joseph Wright

What did I do, step by step:
Press windows key, and press the arrow down - this is apparently where all the programs are hidden now, I had no idea. There I found the MikTex Package manager, named only "Package Manager", so it was not findable through search previously. Synchronize database, then find datetime2 and install it.

Comment: The "MikTeX-pdfTeX" comment was _your_ comment ...

Comment: Wrong copy paste :)